# What could be the better Database to make a book reader one or more books?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mongodb

I am thinking about a personal book reading mobile app project. I have a total of 13 different books. Each book has 10 chapters and each chapter has its own content. It should have the feature of downloading a particular book in local storage on the phone.

What could be a better database system for this problem? I got different ideas about MySQL, MongoDB, etc. I wanted to know how database experts think about this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Android and iOS rules out most of the big players. If I were you, I'd go with SQLite - it's already in every phone anyway - plus loads of help out in the interweb! Question **will** be closed as it's a "shopping-list". Go to the help and read up on what's on-topic here - you will then be able to ask questions which are on-topic! :-)

Comment: That sounds like a few files.  Do you need a "user" table, some login credentials, a list of who has downloaded what, etc?

Comment: For a *personal*, *mobile* app, SQLite is certainly a valid candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is likely to be closed, unfortunately, because it's the type of question not well-fit for a site like this. That being said, the database systems you listed are server based, and assumptively your question is about which database system your client side mobile app should use.

A popular choice from a relational standpoint is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) because of its portability and it's free. A NoSQL option from an established brand is [Couchbase Mobile](https://www.couchbase.com/products/mobile), and another popular choice from a company not going anywhere anytime soon (Google) is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). Additionally, MongoDB offers a mobile version as well known as [Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/realm).

Your options are also going to depend on the frameworks you're writing your client mobile application in, and which platforms your mobile app will support. Regardless of what you choose, both relational databases and NoSQL databases have equal pros and cons. Also a word of warning that there's a lot of misinformation out there regarding one database system being *faster* than others, but all of them are equally performant, generally speaking, when implemented correctly. My personal preference is a relational data store, and my go to is SQLite when building mobile apps.